# How can I hide my navbar until the user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am upgrading and old website using bootstrap 3 and I had an option for hiding the menu(navbar) when user was not logged in and would like to do this with bootstrap. And have a value for enabling it when the user logins. 
Below is my code in the .cs file for the default page where it asks for login. Can I add an ID to navbar? as per example

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ID="Menu">
```

? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using DA; //erc
using System.Data;//erc
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;//erc

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (Session["oUser"] == null)
    {
        //Set the focus to the username textbox

        // this.txtUsername.Focus();
    }

    else
    {   //find user and redirect to oRole.startPage
        OBJ_User oUser = new OBJ_User();
        DA_Roles daRole = new DA_Roles();
        OBJ_Role oRole = new OBJ_Role();

        oUser = (OBJ_User)Session["oUser"];
        oRole = daRole.getRoleById(oUser.role_FK);

        //Redirect!
        Response.Redirect(oRole.startPage);
    }


    //Desabilita el menu hasta que se entre el login funcionaba antes de hacer el cambio a bootstrap 3 
    //Control Menu1 = bootstrap_navbar_enabled;

    //if (Menu1 != null)
   // {
        //Menu1.Visible = false;
   // }
}
```

View code:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SACPAN.master.cs" Inherits="SACPAN" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head runat="server">
   <title>SDEC</title>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src='Scripts/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
 </head>

  <body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
     EnablePageMethods="true"/>--%>
    <%--<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>--%>

    <%-- Sistema para Autorización de Comercios del Programa de Asistencia 
 Nutricional--%>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/OCIN.png" alt="OCINBANNER" 
 width="250" height="300">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <%-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --%>
   <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/default.aspx">
  <img alt="home" src="images/home.png" width="30" height="30">
  </a>
</div>

<%-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --%>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/entitiesViewAll.aspx">Entidades</a></li>
  <%-- Arreglar el dropdown de Establecimientos--%>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="False">Establecimientos <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/establishmentsViewAll.aspx">Establecimientos</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/establishmentsByStatus.aspx">Establecimientos Cancelados</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    <li><a href="/claimsViewAll.aspx">Querellas</a></li>
    <li><a href="/legalViewAll.aspx">Legales</a></li>
    <li><a href="/establishmentsMap.aspx">Mapa</a></li>
   <%-- Arreglar el dropdown de Informes--%>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Informes <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/Informes/transFile.aspx">Archivo Transmisión</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/Informes/reportes.aspx">Informes</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
   </ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Alarmas <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/admin/loginsViewAll.aspx">Accesos al Sistema</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/transFileViewAll.aspx">Archivos de Transmisión</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
  <%-- Arreglar el dropdown (parent) de Administracion--%>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administración <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
           <%--Submenu --%>

         <li> <a href="#">Mantenimiento de Accesso</a><li>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">

        <li><a href="/admin/usersViewAll.aspx">Usuarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/rolesViewAll.aspx">Roles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/accessViewAll.aspx">Funciones</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>

       </ul>
              </li>
           <%--Submenu --%>
     <li> <a href="#">Mantenimiento de Establecimientos</a><li>
      <ul class="dropdown-submenu">

        <li><a href="/admin/activityViewAll.aspx">Actividades</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/activityreasonsViewAll.aspx">Razones de Actividades</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/catsViewAll.aspx">Categorías</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/banksViewAll.aspx">Entidades Bancarias</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/statusViewAll.aspx">Estatus de Comerciante</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/legalStructsViewAll.aspx">Estructuras Legales</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/regionsViewAll.aspx">Regiones y Municipios</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/servViewAll.aspx">Servicios</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/docsViewAll.aspx">Tipos de Documentos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/businessTypesViewAll.aspx">Tipos de Negocio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/phoneTypesViewAll.aspx">Tipos de Telefono</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/contactRelViewAll.aspx">Tipos de Propietarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/SSTypesViewAll.aspx">Tipos de Seguro Social</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>

       </ul>
              </li>
       <%--Submenu --%>
  <li><a href="#">Mantenimientos Adicionales</a></li>
      <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li><a href="/admin/SSTypesViewAll.aspx">Datos Variables</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/exceptionsViewAll.aspx">Excepciones del Sistema</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
           </ul>
              </li>
   </ul>
  <%-- El dropdown de Ayuda --%>
  <li class="dropdown">

      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ayuda <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/manuales/manualUsuario.htm">Manual de Usuario - Establecimiento</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/manuales/manualAdmin.htm">Manual de Usuario - Administración</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
   </ul>
      </li>

  <li><a href="/salir.aspx">Salir</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: where is your view code?

Comment: Sorry will add it now.

Comment: @Timggwp I added it now

Comment: @isherwood thanks, ok

Comment: You can lock the html element with a C# code and then give the access to users that belong to a determined role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to hide the navbar on the login webpage.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
 <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 //Hide Navbar
 var scrollp=0;
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // hide .navbar first
        $(".navbar").hide();

    });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: I added a NOACCESS page as well and improved the security. This page brings back the user without authorization to the login page ( default)